# How to write a classed based view in Django when we have an Order model that has multiple OrderRow records?

Tags: django

I have an Order model such as below:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ORDER_STATUS, default="D")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.customer.name + " Order No. " + str(self.pk)
```

and OrderRow:

```
class OrderRow(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey("products.Product", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.ForeignKey("products.Unit", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.product + " " + self.quantity + " " + self.unit
```

I need to write a classed based view than when user enters in this page a new order automatically created for current user and the user be able to add OrderRows to the current Order.

Answer (score 0):

I think this best approach for save Order and related items of Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Add more fields as needed

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    # Add more fields as needed
```

Another solution is you can save order items in **`JsonField()`** but, I not recommended this approach.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    order_items = models.JSONField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    # Add more fields as needed

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_number
```